# WORDPRESS Background video lagging but not on preview

Tags: wordpress, video, background, preview

I have a very weird problem with my http://gambit.co site. Im using Visual Composer plugin with child of twentysixteen theme. When i run site normally then background video is stuttering. Offcourse when you pause it and wait a little bit then after awhile it runs smoothly. But not from the stright beginning.
But when i log in, go to edit screen of my page and run a preview of it then it runs much better (without stuttering). 
I tested it on chrome, opera and firefox, all in private mode to make sure they didnt use previously buffered video. Result is always the same.

Ive already sent a question to VC developers but i have a feeling that this problem is connected with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to chache the Video on the Webserver? Maybe you can use a code to let the Visitor buffer the Video first before he can play it smooth?

Comment: This should be   a comment

Comment: Well im doing some optimizations now anyway, and caching will be one of them but the main question is why video in preview mode runs significantly faster than in normal mode?